# viewport shading : how can I enable light presets in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, lighting

I'm watching a tutorial an noticed that its author has a default light setup enabled (HDRI in the background, two spheres in the right bottom corner).

[image]

I would like to use this, but cannot find it in the viewport shading options.

How can I enable it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Turn the World Opacity up to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is in *Material Preview* mode, in this mode you'll have the default HDRI effect but you won't see it as background. In order to see it and the 2 spheres you can directly choose the *Shading* workspace:

[image]

Or in the *Viewport Shading* push the *World Opacity* up to 1:

[image]

and in order to see the 2 spheres, in the *Viewport Overlays*, enable *HDRI Preview*:

[image]